# Output parameter is always null with multi.Read

Tags: c#, dapper

We are using [Dapper.Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) extensively and are very happy with it. However we have come across an issue when trying to retrieve output parameters from stored procedures using **multi.Read**:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters(); 
p.Add("@id", id); 
p.Add("TotalRows", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output); 

using (var multi = cnn.QueryMultiple(string.Format("dbo.[{0}]", spName), p,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{  
    int TotalRows = p.Get<int>("@TotalRows"); //This is always null

    var results = multi.Read<New_Supplier>().ToList<IDBSupplier>();
    var areas = multi.Read<node>().ToList<IDBNode>();
    var categories = multi.Read<node>().ToList<IDBNode>();
    int TotalRows = multi.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault(); // This works

}
```

However, if we use the **connection.Query** syntax to get a single resultset the output parameter is populated:

```
var result = cnn.Query<New_Supplier>(string.Format("spname"), p,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<New_Supplier>();
int TotalRows = p.Get<int>("@TotalRows");
```

The error is that the sqlValue of AttachedParam on the output parameter in the Dapper DynamicParameters is always null.

To work around this we have added the value of the output parameter to the result sets of the stored procedure and are reading it that way.

Why is the parameter always null?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a TDS stream, the `OUT` parameters are *at the end*. In your `Query<T>` example, you have *consumed the TDS stream*:

```
var result = cnn.Query<New_Supplier>(string.Format("spname"), p,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<New_Supplier>();
int TotalRows = p.Get<int>("@TotalRows");
```

so because you have consumed the stream, the new parameter values have been reached, and you should have the values available. In the `QueryMultiple` example, you **have not** reached the end of the TDS stream. Try moving the `p.Get`:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters(); 
p.Add("@id", id); 
p.Add("TotalRows", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output); 

using (var multi = cnn.QueryMultiple(string.Format("dbo.[{0}]", spName), p,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{      
    var results = multi.Read<New_Supplier>().ToList<IDBSupplier>();
    var areas = multi.Read<node>().ToList<IDBNode>();
    var categories = multi.Read<node>().ToList<IDBNode>();
}
int TotalRows = p.Get<int>("@TotalRows");
```

If *that* doesn't work, let me know ;p

Comment: Thanks Marc, it works. I *knew* it had to be something simple but just couldn't see it....

Comment: @Simon it is probably obvious now, but just to add: you get exactly the same behavior when using ADO.NET directly.